# Compatibility of queries written in SQL Server 2012 with SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

Can queries designed and written for SQL Server 2012 be used as is on SQL Server 2016. We are planning an upgrade of SQL Server and want minimal manual intervention in order to transition our work

Answer (score 9):

SQL Server is always backwards compatible, with the exception of items listed on the [deprecated features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/discontinued-database-engine-functionality-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017) list.

The query optimizer has changes that may result in performance increases, and in some circumstances, performance decreases.

Microsoft's [Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-2017), provides a way to find deprecated functionality in use by your database.

> The Data Migration Assistant helps discover issues that can affect an upgrade to an on-premises SQL Server. These are described as compatibility issues and are organized in the following categories:
>
> - Breaking changes
> - Behavior changes
> - Deprecated features

Microsoft also provides this list of [breaking changes to database engine features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/breaking-changes-to-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017).

Ensure you test the upgrade first in a non-production environment.

The following script can be used to create two Extended Events sessions that log the use of deprecated features and final-support features:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM sys.dm_xe_sessions xes 
    WHERE xes.name = 'DeprecationFinalSupportEvents'
    )
BEGIN
    ALTER EVENT SESSION DeprecationFinalSupportEvents ON SERVER STATE = STOP;
    DROP EVENT SESSION DeprecationFinalSupportEvents ON SERVER;
END
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM sys.dm_xe_sessions xes 
    WHERE xes.name = 'DeprecationAnnouncmentEvents'
    )
BEGIN
    ALTER EVENT SESSION DeprecationAnnouncmentEvents ON SERVER STATE = STOP;
    DROP EVENT SESSION DeprecationAnnouncmentEvents ON SERVER;
END
GO

DECLARE @LogPath VARCHAR(260);
DECLARE @FinalSupportPathETL VARCHAR(260);
DECLARE @FinalSupportPathMTA VARCHAR(260);
DECLARE @DepPathETL VARCHAR(260);
DECLARE @DepPathMTA VARCHAR(260);

SELECT @LogPath = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(path)
    , CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(path)) + 1, LEN(path) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(path)) + 1))
FROM sys.traces;

SET @FinalSupportPathETL = @LogPath + '\DeprecationFinalSupportEvents.etl';
SET @FinalSupportPathMTA = @LogPath + '\DeprecationFinalSupportEvents.mta';
SET @DepPathETL = @LogPath + 'DeprecationAnnouncmentEvents.etl';
SET @DepPathMTA = @LogPath + 'DeprecationAnnouncmentEvents.mta';

DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cmd = '
CREATE EVENT SESSION DeprecationFinalSupportEvents ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.deprecation_final_support (
    ACTION  (
        sqlserver.database_id
        , sqlserver.sql_text
        , sqlserver.session_id
        , sqlserver.tsql_stack
    )
)
ADD TARGET package0.asynchronous_file_target (
    SET FILENAME = ''' + @FinalSupportPathETL + '''
        , METADATAFILE = ''' + @FinalSupportPathMTA + '''
);

ALTER EVENT SESSION DeprecationFinalSupportEvents ON SERVER
STATE = START;
';
PRINT @cmd;
EXEC (@cmd);

SET @cmd = '
CREATE EVENT SESSION DeprecationAnnouncmentEvents ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.deprecation_announcement
(
    ACTION (
        sqlserver.database_id
        , sqlserver.sql_text
        , sqlserver.session_id
        , sqlserver.tsql_stack
        , sqlserver.username
        , sqlserver.client_hostname
        , sqlserver.database_name
        )
)
ADD TARGET package0.asynchronous_file_target (
    SET FILENAME = ''' + @DepPathETL + '''
        , METADATAFILE = ''' + @DepPathMTA + '''
);

ALTER EVENT SESSION DeprecationAnnouncmentEvents ON SERVER
STATE = START;
';
PRINT @cmd;
EXEC (@cmd);
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps can also be helpful during evaluation of upgrade possibility:

[**Database Experimentation Assistant**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54090)

Database Experimentation Assistant (DEA) is an experimentation solution for SQL Server upgrades. DEA can help you evaluate a targeted version of SQL Server for a specific workload. Customers who are upgrading from earlier SQL Server versions (starting with 2005) to a more recent version of SQL Server can use the analysis metrics that the tool provides.

DEA analysis metrics include:

- Queries that have compatibility errors
- Degraded queries and query plans
- Other workload comparison data